# Is there a way to hide the HTML tags in quick edit view for 2013 lists

Tags: 2013, list

Is there a way to hide the HTML tags that appear when the quick edit view is being using in a sharepoint 2013 list?

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcNl7.jpg

I saw a few things online that mentioned editing the xslt file, but i'm not sure if that would apply to the quick edit view.

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible way and the easiest one is to go to List Settings and modify the individual columns to show only rich text and not enhanced rich text.

[image]

This always works in most of the scenarios.